# Continuity of number sets

Tags: real-analysis

It sounds like an analysis question to a college freshman. I hope It does not annoys anyone. Consider a natural number. Naturally the subsequent number belongs to the real set. I conjecture if the immediate subsequent number belongs to rational or irracional set.

I thank in advance.
Besta regards,
Bruno

Comment: I've left an answer assuming "the subsequent number" to a given natural number is the subsequent *natural* number. There is, however, no least real number $>n$, since if $m>n$ so is $(m+n)/2$.

Comment: All real numbers are either irrational or rational but not both. Given any real number, there is no "next" real number.

Answer (score 0):

The successor of a natural number is natural, and by definition the integers include all naturals, and any integer $n=n/1$ is included in the rationals.

Comment: Thank you. My doubt, however, is regarding the continuity of real number set. Recall the classic representation of numbers in a Venn Diagram. Hence, if one consider the numbers between 0 and 1, all numbers between them, extrema inclusive, are either rational or irrational. Does It make sense to evoke suscetibility under real numbers, since the aforementioned same relation is valid for every two real numbers m and n?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto I haven't a clue what you're talking about.

Comment: Please, read carefully what I type.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto I have. At some point, you'll have to explain what it means to evoke susceptibility under $\Bbb R$.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. Does the concept is even invokable? Since we work here with a field which plays an important role in pure mathematics, it is crucial to use the proper words, when necessary. I will try to reformulate, if it is more understandable: Which property or definition makes the real numbers continuum?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto I feel like you're trying to reach precise notions [such](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) [as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set). But at any rate, real numbers, unlike natural numbers, don't have successors: if $x<y$, $x<\frac{x+y}{2}<y$.

Comment: Thank you. This the answer I was expecting. Thank you.